# Widget Areas Still Appearing in WP ADMIN When They Shouldn't

Tags: widgets, admin, wp-admin, register-sidebar

I had a bunch of "Widget Areas" registered for my theme. I removed a few and added a few. The ones which I removed, I deleted the code which is hooked on `widgets_init` for registering the sidebars. I have also "unregistered" the old "widget areas".

I've looked in the database, and see no references to these Widget Areas. However, for some reason, when I navigate to `WP ADMIN -> Appearance -> Widgets` the old "Widget Areas" are still appearing, when they shouldn't be. The code which registers them has been removed, and they've already been "unregistered".

Is there some sort of cache for registered widget areas or something?

Comment: Ugh, you won't believe it... I deleted the files which were registering the old widget areas on my local copy, but the changes didn't reflect on the remote server apparently. So they were continuing to register the widget areas. Amateur mistake. Always check remote files.

Comment: Nut... don't believe it.